# Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy to another format in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that asks for the user to input the date in the format mm/dd/yyyy and convert it. So, if the user input 01/01/2009, the program should display January 01, 2009. This is my program so far. I managed to convert the month, but the other elements have a bracket around them so it displays January [01] [2009].

```
date=input('Enter a date(mm/dd/yyy)')
replace=date.replace('/',' ')
convert=replace.split()
day=convert[1:2]
year=convert[2:4]
for ch in convert:
    if ch[:2]=='01':
        print('January ',day,year )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you had a look at what `convert` actually contains?

Comment: it displays:['01', '01', '2009']

Comment: Do you understand how slicing works?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use a combination of `strptime()` and `strftime()` from `datetime` module which is a part of python standard library ([docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_input = input('Enter a date(mm/dd/yyyy): ')
Enter a date(mm/dd/yyyy): 11/01/2013
>>> date_object = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> print(date_object.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
November 01, 2013
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look into python's datetime library which will take care of interpreting dates for you. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
d = input('Enter a date(mm/dd/yyy)')

# now convert the string into datetime object given the pattern
d = datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y")

# print the datetime in any format you wish.
print d.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

You can check what %m, %d and other identifiers stand for here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion use [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c), which infers the format by itself:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('01/05/2009').strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'January 05, 2009'
>>> parse('2009-JAN-5').strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'January 05, 2009'
>>> parse('2009.01.05').strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'January 05, 2009'
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it by the slashes

```
convert = replace.split('/')
```

and then create a dictionary of the months:

```
months = {1:"January",etc...}
```

and then to display it do:

```
print months[convert[0]] + day + year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_string = input('Enter a date using the mm/dd/yyyy format: ')
date_list = date_string.split('/')
month = date_list[0]
day = date_list[1]
year_ = date_list[2]
print(month, day, ',', year_ )
input('Press enter to end: ')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code.